# Issue with Quickbooks Web Connector

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have version 2.2.0.94 installed (version needed) on a Windows 10 computer running Quickbooks 2018.  It's fully updated but we are getting an uncaught exception when it launches.

I have also ran the install diagnostics tool and all came out there as well.  We don't have any issues with Quickbooks itself - just the web connector.

Any ideas?

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.anyAppScheduled()
   at QBWebConnector.ScheduleManager.Scheduler_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at QBWebConnector.EventManager.OnClockTicked(Object sender)
   at QBWebConnector.QBWebConnectorWPF.Clock_Ticked(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
QBWebConnector
    Assembly Version: 2.2.0.94
    Win32 Version: 2.2.0.94
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Common%20Files/Intuit/QuickBooks/QBWebConnector/QBWebConnector.exe
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsBase
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4001.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/PresentationCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xaml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xaml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
QBWCUtil
    Assembly Version: 2.2.0.94
    Win32 Version: 2.2.0.94
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Common%20Files/Intuit/QuickBooks/QBWebConnector/QBWCUtil.DLL
----------------------------------------
QBWCCommon
    Assembly Version: 2.2.0.94
    Win32 Version: 2.2.0.94
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/QBWCCommon/v4.0_2.2.0.94__82cc56431f1a971d/QBWCCommon.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
QBWCInterfaces
    Assembly Version: 2.2.0.94
    Win32 Version: 2.2.0.94
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/QBWCInterfaces/v4.0_2.2.0.94__82cc56431f1a971d/QBWCInterfaces.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero2
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero2/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemXml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemXml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationTypes
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationTypes/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationTypes.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationProvider
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationProvider/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationProvider.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4075.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Web/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Did you load a `.QWC` file into the Web Connector? If so, post it. Also, did you contact Intuit support yet?

Comment: Nope - error came up at initial launch.  I did not contact intuit support yet - was hoping for a quick fix.

Comment: I would re-install, and if you still have problems contact Intuit support -- StackOverflow is generally not the place to get general software support. I think it'd also be helpful if you provided more details -- Screenshot of exception/error? Where exactly did you get this debug output from (the Web Connector, or some diagnostic tool? What diagnostic tool?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime diagnostics was caused be the missing "Scheduler" key in the system registry.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Intuit -> QBWebConnector -> Scheduler

After adding that, the issue was that the Quickbooks Company File was moved to a new computer, which meant that the owner / file id values needed to be updated in the .qwc config file before it would load up on that company file.

Hoping this helps out someone else!

Comment: Hey @Aaron, we're having this issue on Windows Server 2012 with Terminal Services. One of our users is getting this .NET error and I have made sure they have the Scheduler key as you indicated. Our QB Comp File was NOT recently moved to a new computer...afaik nothing has changed in our setup and this just started popping up. Any thoughts? Would I still need to edit the .qwc config? If so, how would I know exactly how I need to edit it? Also, where can I find general info on how to edit that config? - don't think I've ever needed to do so before. Thanks so much!